# What does *(int *) mean in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#define value1 *(int*)46
```

I came across a similar statement in an header file for address definitions of interrupts(registers) and peripherals for a microcontroller .

How I interpret it?

We are making 46 a pointer type by typecasting it and using * operator to extract value from it.So the value at location 46 must be stored in value1.

What happens?

```
printf("%d",&value1)
```

This returns the address of x as 46.

```
printf("%d",value1)
```

This gives runtime error.Runtime error also results when we try to access the values of x.

Following are my questions:

1. What exactly is `*(int *)46` mean?
2. What is value1? An integer pointer or an integer

Any more info and extra comments about this or any other way to use pointers is most welcome for a beginner like me.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You seem to be conflatiing `value1` and `x`.  Are they really the same thing, or is it a typo?

Comment: There is no declaration for x in this question.

Comment: Which MCU? What the datasheet says about address 46?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry.It's value1 all along.It was a typo.Changed it

Comment: @LPs :

Here's the line:

#define value1 \*(someStruct\*)46

  where someStruct is a structure and 46 is the address of the SFR.

Comment: ... that means that probably the _some struct_ defines SFRs registers...

Comment: How about getting a C book and start learning yourself? This is not tutoring site. Yolu will not get the required whole picture from particular questions & answers on the internet.

Comment: Such a declaration for peripheral registers is plain wrong. It should use fixed width types and **has to** be qualified `volatile`.If that is not, I'd strongly recommend to change the toolchain or the vendor. It definitively results in incorrect code.

Comment: Yes it was a volatile type struct. What I understood from tutorials on C pointers I have mentioned in my interpretation of the code.

But putting volatile doesn't make a difference to the code.Compilation is successful but there's a runtime error.Following is the dummy code I'm trying on Ideone :

**ideone.com/diTj5h**

It seems accessing the values in the struct causes error.

Answer (score 10):

With `x = *(int*)46`, you are reading `sizeof int` bytes from memory, starting at address 46.

With `*(int*)46 = x`, you are writing `sizeof int` bytes into memory, starting at address 46.

Of course, this operation should be preceded by a proper allocation of that memory block.

---

Please note that depending on your platform (underlying HW architecture + designated compiler), it is not guaranteed that the actual operation will indeed start at the given memory address.

More specifically, if the address is not aligned to `int` (not divisible by `sizeof int`) and your platform does not support unaligned load/store operations, then the result of such operation will not be what you'd expect. For example, you might get an 'illegal memory access' exception, or the operation might start at the nearest smaller address which is aligned to `int`.

---

I should probably emphasize that if a block of `int` has not been properly allocated at that memory address prior to this operation, then the result of such operation is undefined by the C language standard **regardless** of the previous conditions that I've mentioned (the specific value of the address and the type of platform in use).

---

EDIT:

OK, I forgot who I'm dealing with on this website.

Will delete this answer shortly in order not to get in trouble with SO lawyers.

I'll just write UB next time, so everyone here will remain satisfied (and the actual question will remain unanswered)...

Comment: @LPs: Thanks :) I still think it's more likely a lawyer rather than an avenger. I haven't picked on anyone here recently (and hardly ever in general).

Comment: The third paragraph doesn't make much sense. First you say it is undefined and then you say it is undefined only if memory wasn't allocated. So which is it?

Comment: @2501: Well, the third paragraph is the more accurate one. In the second paragraph I meant "won't do what you expect" rather than "undefined by the language standard". So in essence you're right about the slight mis-phrasing here, wasn't sure how to express it so that both the practical problems and the official answer will be reflected.

Comment: I'm asking about the third paragraph specifically, and how it contradicts itself. Here it is: *I should probably emphasize that the result of such operation is undefined by the C language standard regardless of the previous conditions that I've mentioned (the specific value of the address and the type of platform in use). If a block of int has not been properly allocated in memory prior to this operation, then the result of that operation is undefined by the C language standard.* So, which one is it? Always undefined, or not and under which conditions.

Comment: I think _won't do what you expect_ would vary though. Different compilers and different systems can churn out different bytecode. For example using the MPLAB suite to program a PIC18 and a CCS compiler. I could get away with things in one that the other couldn't; but so-long as there's no OS involvement, you want a pointer to an address, you got it. Hope ya know what you're doing with it.

Comment: @2501: Yeah, you're right about that one too. I should settle this by moving the "If a block of `int` has not been properly allocated in memory prior to this operation, then" part to appear before the "the result of such operation is undefined by the C language standard".

Comment: @M4rc: I was only trying to illustrate some "real time" problems that can (and will) emerge under those specific conditions (unaligned memory address + no support for unaligned load/store operations). I thought it would be a little more useful than stating "UB" if you know what I mean...

Comment: @barakmanos absolutely -- and I was more or less just adding a little dynamic-ness to it (no pun).  I would much rather read your post versus the dozens of "UB! UB! UB!" bandwagoneers and C/++....well...you know...

Comment: The third paragraph is not accurate. The C-standard explicitly allows the casting of an integer to a pointer, 6.3.2.3–5. Whether it is invalid depends and **only** depends on the previous conditions, so it is not illegal *regardless* of them: *An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.*

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Casting - yes. Accessing for reading or writing - that depends on the platform (which is a different way of saying that the language standard leaves it undefined IMO). And in OP's example, that first `*` means memory access. So it's not just a pointer casting.

Comment: If the pointer is valid, it is legal to apply the indirection operator on it. For the C-standard a pointer you are not allowed to apply an indirection operator on it, *is* an invalid pointer. But this is not the point: I'm talking about the third paragraph that states, that the address has to be "allocated" (what is the wrong term in any case) prior to the access. That's not correct. The C-standard does not state such a condition, at least I do not know the place, where it is defined. In a freestanding implementation such a "pointer literal" is needed.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Well, I believe that "if a block of `int` has been properly allocated at that memory address" is just another way of saying that the pointer is valid. It doesn't have to be dynamic allocation of course. It can be a local variable or whatever. If there is no memory management (OS, virtual memory, etc), and that address is accessible by the memory bus, then I would consider this the same as "properly allocated".

Comment: @barakmanos No, you can't. Neither from the natural meaning of the word nor of the meaning in the C-standard. "I know that it is a valid address" and "it is allocated" has completely different meanings.

Answer (score 7):

Explicitly converting an integer to a pointer, your `(int*)46` part, is what the C standard calls "implementation defined", that is it depends on your particular platform what happens here. If your platform defines `46` to be a valid address, a port number or whatever, dereferencing it with a `*` in front should read or write there, at that address.

If your platform doesn't allow for that, this can give you a segmentation fault on execution, namely if you are on a PC or similar. This kind of platforms protect you from writing at random addresses, for your own and everybody else' safety.

If you'd happen to program for a more restricted environment such as an embedded system, there will be no such protection and things can go very wrong. For this reason the C standard requires an explicit conversion (a cast) from any integer value to a pointer value. By that you are telling the compiler that you know what you are doing.

Comment: Platforms which generate segfaults or any other defined reaction are much more rare than those which just "do something".

Comment: @Olaf at address `46`? Really? This low range is usually protected, isn't it?

Comment: Not on most platforms C is used for. there is more than x86 or ARMv7A/8. You completely forget about embedded systems. On most either no protection is available and they just yield whatever is on the bus or they have RAM, Flash, Peripherals. But typically no MMU/MPU hardware (Cortex-M can have MPUs, but still this area often contains valid addresses).

Comment: @Olaf, we probably just have a different measure for "most". I'll modify my text a bit.

Answer (score -1):

(int *)46 means take the number 46 and typecast it into an address of type int pointer.   just like (int *)foo would do.  Now that you have it as a pointer to something say int *x;  And you want to access that thing you use another * in front so *x means access the thing that x points at so *(int *)foo means make foo an int * pointer then access the thing that pointer points at.   So *(int *)46 means I want to access the thing at address 46.  Just like foo=46;  *(int *)foo; would mean the same thing.  Without a volatile though the compiler can optimize out actual accesses to that address, so if this is pointing at a hardware peripheral control register it might not work as desired.

Answer (score -2):

`#define value1 *(int*)46` means **pretend** that 46 is a pointer to an int value and look at the int value that the (pseudo-)pointer points at. In almost all cases that won't do anything useful.

Comment: IN a freestanding implementation this is useful.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Generally not in the form shown. Using signed integer constants is a bad idea. And typically hex constants are used.

Comment: Signedness is meaningless here. Whether you prefer hex or decimal notation is a matter of taste. However, I'm pretty sure that this was not the reason to call it "won't do anything useful*.